# Disqus thread migration. Gotchas?

Tags: web-crawlers

I've been migrating a site to a new domain.  The site itself is pretty straightforward (it uses Jekyll), and everything has gone fine -- except migration of Disqus threads.

I've had *partial* success -- some of the threads have migrated successfully, but not all.

I've tried the domain migration wizard (which caught a few), the URL mapper (which caught a few), and the 301 redirect crawler (which caught a few).  But the remaining threads just won't move, no matter which method I use.

So, I suppose I suppose I'm asking if there are any "gotchas" I should know about with this.  When you execute any of these migration tools, it says it will "take awhile."  Does that mean hours?  Days?  I can't tell if it's working, and there's no logging or error reporting that I can see.

Comment: The URL mapper you used, is that the CSV export of the comment treads to map to the new URLs?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the domain migration wizard a few times. The process went smoothly. What got me the first time was that the data didn't transfer immediately, and I assumed it didn't work. Give it a few minutes. Also, make sure you have your data backed up first!

Answer (score 1):

While i am migrating from my blogspot blog to new domain, I used disqus migration tools, Even i worried as my comments was 0 from 2000+, Then after 1 day i seen same comments on my domain url. I am not sure whether its for all url's or not, As i seen almost few url's migrated.